# C++ switch statement calculator

Tags: c++, switch-statement, calculator

I need to make a calculator for C++ using switch statement. Exact instructions are: 
Part #1:

Use a switch-case statement to write a basic calculator program which presents the user with the following menu:

```
  Menu
  =============
  +) Add
  -) Subtract
  *) Multiply
  /) Divide
  x) Exit
  ==============
  Enter your choice:
```

For a user selection of +, -, *, or /, the program prompts for two operands and then performs the calculation and displays the result
If the user selects X or x, the program ends.
If the user selects a character other than +, -, *, /, x, or X, the program displays an error message that the selection is invalid.
Part #2:

Add the following input validation to your solution to Calculator Part #1:

If the user selects the divide choice, /, and second operand is zero, the program responds that “Division by zero is not possible.”

I would love to go through all of my previous attempts but unfortunately I left my drive at home and now I'm down to the wire. I CAN however tell you I was using this type of format:

```
int main()
{
char choice;

cout << "Enter A, B, or C: ";
cin >> choice;

switch (choice)
{
  case 'A': cout << "You entered A.\n";
                break;
  case 'B': cout << "You entered B.\n";
                break;
  case 'C': cout << "You entered C.\n";
                break;
  default: cout << "You did not enter A, B, or C!\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Have no idea why I am so stumped on this one.

Comment: doing your homework?

Comment: And how A,B,C corresponds to + - /  * ?

Comment: Huh?? `'A'`, `'B'` or `'C'` aren't the same choices as from your requirement ``+``, `'-'`, etc.

Comment: Remember that when you read a single character, you read the actual next character in the input buffer. When you enter e.g. `A` as input, and then press the enter key to pass the input to the program, that enter key is also passed to the program, as a newline character. So after you read the entered `A` and next read an input, it will read the newline.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Please search the internet for "StackOverflow c++ calculator switch", this will give you a plethora of examples.

Comment: I was trying to plug in "+-/*" instead of "a" "b" "c" or assign value to "a" "b" "c". Honestly just posted to show the STRUCTURE I have been trying to go off of. Not the EXACT code.  It's so frustrating because I honestly do try and yes as a newcomer A LOT of my code makes no sense sometimes. So you can either help or move on. Pooya congrats on your 10+ years. I have barley 10+ weeks so don't feel so powerful when you put down newbies. No need to put anyone down. And to answer the question I am MOSTLY confused about the correct way to assign these operations. ie "+ - / * "

Comment: @user6122965 You had a working "format" but didn't provide what exactly was the problem with your actual code. "it doesn't work"  or "i'm stumped" doesn't cut it. You need to provide details such as "I tried a switch case with '*' but was getting error x" or something like that. It's part of the learning process to learn how to ask questions rather than shoving your code at someone and saying "fix it".

Comment: Thomas's answer below work or you could use if/else statements if you haven't learned about switch yet. Either would work, it's personal pref at that point

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your solution is:

```
// Forward declarations.
void Add();
void Divide();
void Multiply();
void Subtract();
//...
switch(menu_choice)
{
    case '*':  Multiply(); break;
    case '+':  Add(); break;
    case '/':  Divide(); break;
    case '-':  Subtract(); break;
    default: // for you to implement
}
```

Like you said, I "plugged in" the symbols for the letters.

Comment: I saw the "case" examples before and honestly thought I shouldn't use that because we haven't even used case in class yet. With the switch statements requirement is the case the most appropriate way?

Comment: How would you use a `switch` statement without `case`?  Your other alternatives are:  1) if-else ladder 2) Tables with function pointers.